# JSF - Composite Component include js file

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, composite-component

how can i add a js file to my own composite component taglib?

I have following strucuture:

src/main/resources/META-INF/ 
- mytaglib.xml 
- faces-config.xml

src/main/resources/META-INF/resources 
- myComponent.xhtml

In myComponent.xhtml i want to add a js file. How can i do this and where i have to put this js file?

Solved - see my comment

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
<title>An button with JS</title>
</head>
<body>
<cc:interface>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="test.js" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:commandLink value="test" onclick="myFunc();" />
</cc:implementation>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Okay while playing i found the solution:

The <h:outputScript library="js" name="test.js" target="head" /> has to be in the <cc:implementation> and the js-file has to be in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/js

Comment: You should post the answer as an answer, not as a question edit.